# Socket Latency on Windows is much higher compared to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, tcp

We are running a Socket based communication between two program (localhost) and we noticed that when we use the 'exact' same code (It's Python and MATLAB) on Windows and Linux, Linux has much less latency compared to Windows. Our program run on Windows much slower compared to Linux. The hardware for both platform are roughly similar so we are isolating it to OS differences.

My question is

1. What is the expected TCP latency? Wireshark show us that the time between packets is 0.02 second / 50 Hz.
2. Is there any way to reduce TCP latency on Windows?
   As a Note, we already use  s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1) on both Linux and Windows (At Python).

Comment: From various sources, Python on Windows can be slower in different cases and Microsoft has invested there, https://www.theregister.com/2021/05/13/guido_van_rossum_cpython_3_11/ I don't expect any non-Python guys can give you much guidance (since you didn't use the Python tags).

Comment: @LexLi Actually we also done the socket connection in other language, the trend is also the same. I put python here because it is the most common language..

Comment: Unless you use a Microsoft language such as C# to reproduce the same issue, I doubt whether that trend truly exists.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.